# String subdivision and data return problem

Tags: java, string, jdbc, split, db2

in addition to returning the db2.get (i) .getEnumDesc () strings which are normal strings.
there are some strings like: 1 - Selected house in db2.get (i) .getEnumDesc ()
I have to cut -> 1 -
I have translated the selected part of the house and then reassembled it.
1 - select house

in practice, in output, not only normal strings have to be returned, but also strings with numbers, ie 1 - select house
in printed output:
es.
house
hello
1 - select
2 - bye
etc...

```
public void getTraduttoreIt_ENUM_NLS() throws Exception {
        List<EnumNls> db2 = getListEnumNls();
        List<DizioPt> sqlServer = getListDizioPt();

        BufferedWriter scrivi = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("C:/Users/francesco/Desktop/Table_THERA.ENUM_NLS_Sez4.txt"));
        System.out.println("-------------------WRITE FILE N°4--------TRANSLATION------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < db2.size(); i++) {  
            for (int j = 0; j < sqlServer.size(); j++) {
                if (db2.get(i).getEnumDesc().equals(sqlServer.get(j).getKeyword())) {

                    System.out.println(
                            "INSERT INTO THERA.ENUM_NLS VALUES" + "(" + "'" + db2.get(i).getAttributeRef().trim() + "'"
                                    + "," + "'" + db2.get(i).getEnumValue().trim() + "'" + "," + "'" + "en" + "'" + ","
                                    + "'" + sqlServer.get(j).getTraduzione().trim() + "'" + ")" + ";");

                    scrivi.write("INSERT INTO THERA.ENUM_NLS VALUES" + "(" + "'" + db2.get(i).getAttributeRef().trim()
                            + "'" + "," + "'" + db2.get(i).getEnumValue().trim() + "'" + "," + "'" + "en" + "'" + ","
                            + "'" + sqlServer.get(j).getTraduzione().trim() + "'" + ")" + ";");

                    scrivi.newLine();
                    scrivi.flush();
                }
            }

        }
        scrivi.close();
    }

}
```

in practice, in output, not only normal strings have to be returned, but also strings with numbers, ie 1 - select house
in printed output:
es.
house
hello
1 - select
2 - bye
etc...

Comment: Please learn about prepared statements and parameterized queries. Concatenating values into a query string like you're doing is unsafe (sql injection) and can also cause other hard to diagnose problems.

Comment: the problem that there are no errors: That I can't implement this problem: In the double for loop I did, in addition to returning normal strings, it must also return strings starting with numbers. es. Output to print: home, dog, 1 - mouse, 2 - red
I only print dog and home, instead it doesn't print 1 - mouse and 2 - red because when I make equality between a record of the first table and the record of the second table I find only home and dog. YOU MUST MAKE THE REGULAR EXPRESSION THAT I DO NOT KNOW APPLY.

Comment: if I cut the string "1 -" and make the equality between the first mouse record of one table and the other record of the other table, I find myself mouse and then I have to concatenate the string translated from Italian to English 1 - mouse.

How you do it?

Answer (score 0):

What error(s) are you getting?

Could the string returned from db2.get(i).getEnumValue().trim() or sqlServer.get(j).getTraduzione().trim() have a single quote (') in it?  In which case your SQL statement has a syntax error.  If this is the case, after trim() you could insert a .replaceAll("'", "''") which should solve your the problem.
So db2.get(i).getEnumValue().trim().replaceAll("'", "''") - This is ("\u0027", "\u0027\u0027")

If you are getting a number back, what you have should work, even if the number is part of the string.

Unless your data has to do with "house", I think you are using the wrong English word in describing your situation.
In any case, explain the errors you are seeing and that might help people understand your problem.

Comment: Pattern prefissoDescrizionePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\s*-\\s*)?(.*)");
BufferedWriter scrivi = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/francesco/Desktop/Table_THERA.ENUM_NLS_Sez4.txt"));
for (int i = 0; i < db2.size(); i++) {
Matcher enumDescPulito = prefissoDescrizionePattern.matcher(db2.get(i).getEnumDesc());
for (int j = 0; j < sqlServer.size(); j++) {
if(enumDescPulito.find() == true) {
if (enumDescPulito.equals(sqlServer.get(j).getKeyword())) {

Comment: it only needs to accept the values ​​from 0 to 9, the hyphen and finally all the strings through regular expressions

When I have to print, not only must it print eg.
dog
home
1 - hello
2 - hello
c ....
can you help me implement the code?

Comment: Pattern prefissoDescrizionePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\s*-\\s*)?(.*)");
for (int i = 0; i < db2.size(); i++) { String str = db2.get(i).getEnumDesc();
Matcher matcher = prefissoDescrizionePattern.matcher(str);
for (int j = 0; j < sqlServer.size(); j++) { if (matcher.find()) {String prefisso = matcher.group(1); String descrizione = sqlServer.get(j).getTraduzione();
String risultato = (prefisso != null ? prefisso : "") + descrizione; if (risultato.equals(sqlServer.get(j).getKeyword()))